# Identify "next" and "previous" click in data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add some custom functionality on data table next and previous button. I can access click event using

```
$('#table').on('page.dt', function(){
       // custom code
});
```

but here, I can not identify whether next was clicked or previous. Is there any way to identify this in `page.dt`? I don't want it in callback of data table

Comment: Can you please tell why you don't want it in a DataTable callback function (As that would be an easy way to recognize that) ?

Comment: I want to send value back to the server and it is not working in call back Please check my question for it 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708529/how-to-get-row-data-in-fnserverdata-of-data-table

Comment: You could add your own event handler, eg `$("#table .next-btn").click...` or, referencing  https://datatables.net/reference/event/page you can use the event details `e.target` to know which button was pressed.  But, you'll see from the api doc, that `page.dt` is not just called when a page button is pressed.